# Changing timezone in PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

This is my script which makes an entry into the `orders` table. However currently the time being inserted into the table is not being displayed as my local time!

```
//Retrieve variables
$tableNum = $_POST['tableNum'];
$coverNum = $_POST['coverNum'];

//GET DATE & SET TIME ZONE
date_default_timezone_set(Europe/Dublin);

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

//construct query & execute
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (covers, `table`, placed) VALUES ('$coverNum', '$tableNum', '$date') ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$numrows = mysql_affected_rows();
```

Can anyone suggest a way I can go about fixing my code to display for Europe/Dublin?  The column in my table is `TIMESTAMP`.

With above code my output is this:

**21/02/2013 - 14:30**

Should be this:

**21/02/2013 - 21:30**

Many thanks!

Comment: You might see this a lot, but dont use **mysql_*** commands as they have been deprecated. Use PDO/MySQLi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add quotes around europe/dublin

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked. Accept your answer as soon as I am allowed.

Comment: If you always want to use that time zone you should set date.timezone in php.ini (Don't forget to use a string there too).

Answer (score 0):

When changing the time zone, you need to provide a string as such

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Dublin");
```

More [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
$datetime = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Dublin'))
$datetime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

I like using DateTime because it makes working with timezones simple.